# Synonym request: [seach] → [search]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I just noticed the [seach](/questions/tagged/seach) tag (currently 24 questions). It's an obvious misspelling of [search](/questions/tagged/search).

Can we run through them (many are in need of editing) and then synonymize the tags?

Comment: Are typos normally corrected via synonyms?  (I honestly don't know -- I didn't mean that sarcastically.)

Comment: @BlackVegetable Sometimes, sometimes not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, only the first question in that list looked like it was in dire need of attention. Merged into [search](/questions/tagged/search), all done. Don't really see a need for a synonym.